# How to set min lenght in v-autocomplete in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use [v-autocomplete](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/) UI Component in my code.
How can I set min length to start searching (e.g. 3 symbols)?

By default, min length is 1 symbol and it displays **no-data-text** before I started to enter symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` prop to apply your own filter logic, and change **no-data-text** to show the specific message you want:

```html
<v-autocomplete
   :items="states"
   :filter="customFilter"
   color="white"
   item-text="name"
   :no-data-text= "noDataText"
>     
</v-autocomplete>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
     showNoData: false,
  }
},
methods: {
   customFilter(item, queryText, itemText) {
      if (queryText.length < 3) {
         this.showNoData = false;
         return false;
      }
      this.showNoData = true;
      return itemText.includes(queryText);
      // you can add any logic you want here
   }
},
computed: {
   noDataText() {
     return this.showNoData ? "no matching items" : "search for items";
   }
}
```